# Opened workbook is immediatelly closed without reason

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem that when a macro opens a file then the file is immediately closed without any reason and the macro is finished although there are next steps that should be done.

Below is the code, I marked where the macro is finished.

```
Sub Aktualizace()

Dim Mesic As String, Rok As String

Mesic = Month(Sheets("XY")).Range("A1")
Rok = Year(Sheets("XY")).Range("A1")

If Mesic < 10 Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="path to file A"
Else
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="path to file B"            <-- here it is finished
End If

...
(Here are the next steps for work with the opened file)
...

Calculate
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Can the possible reason for that be the fact the file is opened from network drive instead of a local one?

Comment: Is there any code in the workbook you open?

Comment: Debug code with F8 and see the exact moment the workbook closes

Comment: No there is not any code in the workbook which I open.

Comment: I tried to debug it step by step and when it is on the line Workbook.Open (as marked) then the file is opened and immediatelly closed and macro finished.

Comment: Solved :-)  The problem was that I was there mistake in next steps and then it was not processed and file was immediatelly closed and macro finished quickly. Anyway when I debug it by F8 it automatically continued when file was opened and I thought that macro finished in the middle. Thanks.